# How to get an empty data from API using Alamofire in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, alamofire

I need some assistance again regarding my codes. Bit confuse on how will the empty `data` be reflected from `APIService` going to `ViewController`.

**Here's the JSON**

```
{
 "responseMessage": "No record Found",
 "data": []
}
```

As you can see the `data` is nil.

**Here's the APIService**

```
 typealias getDoctorPayoutSummaryTaskCompletion = (_ latestPayoutSummary: DoctorPayoutSummary?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void

  static func getDoctorPayoutSummary(doctorNumber: String, periodId: Int, completion: @escaping getDoctorPayoutSummaryTaskCompletion) {

    guard let latestPayoutSummaryURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.LatestCreditedAmount.latestPayoutSummary)?periodId=\(periodId)&doctorNumber=\(doctorNumber)") else {
            completion(nil, .invalidURL)
            return
        }

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
           tasks.forEach({ $0.cancel() })
        }


        Alamofire.request(latestPayoutSummaryURL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            guard HelperMethods.reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
                completion(nil, .noNetwork)
                return
            }

            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                completion(nil, .noStatusCode)
                return
            }

            switch(statusCode) {
            case 200:
                guard let jsonData = response.data else {
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                    return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {
                    let currentPayoutSummary = try decoder.decode(RootDoctorPayoutSummary.self, from: jsonData)
                        print(periodId)
                    print(currentPayoutSummary.data ?? "data is nil")
                    print(currentPayoutSummary.data ?? "response is nil")
                    completion(currentPayoutSummary.data, nil)

                } catch {
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                    print(error)
                }

            case 400: completion(nil, .badRequest)
            case 404: completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
            default:
                print("**UNCAPTURED STATUS CODE FROM (getDoctorPayoutSummary)\nSTATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
                completion(nil, .uncapturedStatusCode)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to use breakpoints to track my codes and it does print `data is nil` if the `data` is empty in the `APIService` side. But unfortunately the `getDoctorPayoutSummary` function in the `ViewController` side doesn't recognized if the data is empty. It just recognizes if the `data` is not empty and it runs smoothly.

**Here's the getDoctorPayoutSummary()**

```
 func getDoctorPayoutSummary(doctorNumber: String) {
    SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(.lightGray)
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Processing...")

    APIService.DoctorLatestCreditedAmount.getDoctorPayoutSummary(doctorNumber: doctorNumber, periodId: doctorPayoutWeek[0].periodId!) { (payoutsummary, error) in

        guard let payoutSummaryDetails = payoutsummary, error == nil else {
            if let networkError = error {
                switch networkError {
                case .noRecordFound:
                    self.noRecordView.isHidden = false
                    self.creditedAmountLabel.isHidden = true
                case .noNetwork:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "\(networkError.rawValue)", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                default:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is something went wrong. Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            return
        }


        self.payoutSummary = payoutSummaryDetails
        print(payoutSummaryDetails)

        if self.payoutSummary == nil {
                    self.noRecordView.isHidden = false
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    return
            }

        self.creditedAmountLabel.text = "₱\(self.payoutSummary.creditedAmount ?? 0.0)"
        self.getPatientList()
        self.noRecordView.isHidden = true
        self.week1TableView.reloadData()

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        return
    }

}
```

My apology if I ask too much but I really need help to solve this one so I can move on with other tasks. Asking for your little time to help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Reload table in main async queue DispatchQueue.main.async {  self.table.reloadData }

Comment: @Bista sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is empty it will return empty array, so check

```
if currentPayoutSummary.data.isEmpty {
       print("Data is empty !!")
       completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
}
```

**or**

```
 if currentPayoutSummary.data.count == 0 {
           print("Data is empty !!")
           completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
    }
```

Comment: in which part will I insert your answer?

Comment: Before this line buddy


                    ====>  print(currentPayoutSummary.data ?? "response is nil")

Comment: Please, never `count` and check for zero in Swift. Don't do that. There is `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Check `responseMessage`

   ```
   let currentPayoutSummary = try decoder.decode(RootDoctorPayoutSummary.self, from: jsonData)
   if currentPayoutSummary.responseMessage == "No record Found" {
       completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
   } else {
       completion(currentPayoutSummary.data, nil)
   }
   ```
2. Check if `data` is empty

   ```
   let currentPayoutSummary = try decoder.decode(RootDoctorPayoutSummary.self, from: jsonData)
   if currentPayoutSummary.data.isEmpty {
       completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
   } else {
       completion(currentPayoutSummary.data, nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: It solved my issue. Thank you @vadian you really are a savior.

Answer (score 0):

Use responseData instead of responseJSON